# Android: setSelection having no effect on Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I'm having some problems with setSelection on a Spinner. I set the value to be pre-selected when the spinner is shown in code, but it has no effect and the first alternative in the list is always selected. The code looks like this:

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.edit_event, null);
...
ArrayList<String> routes = new ArrayList<String>();
// routes filled with values at runtime
...
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(GOFdroid.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, routes);
aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  
Spinner destSpinner = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit_event_destination);
  
String dest = events.get(pos).getDestination();
int routesPos = routes.indexOf(dest);
Log.d(TAG, "Dest: " + dest + ", pos: " + routesPos);
destSpinner.setSelection(routesPos);
   
destSpinner.setAdapter(aa);
```

The code works as intended except for the setSelection-part, and I just can't figure out why.

The XML layout of the spinner looks like this (not the entire layout, only the spinner part):

```
// DESTINATION
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Destination:" />
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/edit_event_destination"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:prompt="@string/choose_dest"
   android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
   android:text="" />
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try moving the call to `setSelection()` after the call to `setAdapter()`.

Answer (score 75):

I had similar problem. In my case `setAdaper` and `setSelection` were in correct order! Executed form `onCreate` worked, but when executed from `onResume` had no effect.

The [solution](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-spinnersetselection-finding.html) is to call `setSelection(my_pos, true)`. Notice the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks ! I would have never imagine that a parameter named 'animate' would have this effect...

Comment: Thanks so much! I would not have tried that. I spent two hours on this before finding your post.

Comment: I also had the setselection in OnResume which didn't work. Using the second parameter as you indicated it does, but now the spinner is moved aways from the original position.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was beginning to think I am the problem.

Comment: It seems like a bug in sdk, because still now only works for me the selection with this method...

Comment: On newer Android versions this 'bug' has been fixed, but if you support older devices you will be surprised :) btw  setSelection(my_pos, false) also works fine ....

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I assume the "animate" displays the newly selected option, but can anyone provide some more information on why this is required?

Comment: Worked for me too..but don't know why it's working when animate becomes true.. ;)

Answer (score 40):

You might try

```
mSpinner.post(new Runnable() {        
    public void run() {
      mSpinner.setSelection(1);
    }
  });
```

this will post the runnable action to run as soon as the view is created

Answer (score 31):

In my case none of the answers worked, so I queued the setSelection through a Handler

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {        
    public void run() {
      mSpinner.setSelection(1);
    }
  }, 100);
```

Doing this could cause problems when running on slow devices, but I'm working for a specific device so it's ok to use this hack

Comment: +1, this solved in my case only, previous ones not. I am on Android 2.3.3 onCreate() method, after set the adapter

Comment: +1 I found that this was the only way to get it to work within the OnItemSelectedListener.

Comment: thanks because nothing else worked... but it gives me a bad feeling

Answer (score 4):

None of the previous answers worked for me. What did work, though, was creating the instance variable `mSpinner` in the `onCreateView()` method of my fragment (or in the `onCreate()` method of your activity), then doing this in my `onLoadFinished()` method...

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    //mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    mSpinner.setSelection(mSelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Moving the Spinner & Adapter initialization into the onCreateView (Fragment), was enough for me to get it working in the "onResume()" override function

Answer (score 4):

`Spinner.setSelection()` do not work if you call it before `Spinner.setAdapter()`

Try calling `setSelection()` after the call to setAdapter().

**Reason Behind this** : when you call `Spinner.Selection()` before setting an adapter to it simply means that you are trying to set spinner to custom index by setSelection() when it doesn't contain any data or we can say thats spinner has max item =0.

so `setSelection(1)` means setting index to 1 for spinner which has max item =0; Although spinner itself handles this outofBoundIndex so your app does not crashes.

call to `SetSelection()` should be after setAdapter() only

Also if you have a `Spinner.SetOnItemSelectedListener()` and you have problem that `onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` is tiggered with position value=0 when activity load and then you should use this pattern.

```
Spinner.SetAdapter()
Spinner.setSelection();
Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
The solution is to call setSelection(my_pos, true). Notice the second parameter.
```

Don`t forget, if you call animate, setup layout params then :)
Example:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerLp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) spinner.getLayoutParams();
spinner.setSelection(selectedPositionAge, true);
spinnerLp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
spinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerLp);
```

manually set paddings to spinner need to be reset manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a spinner inside a `fragment : setSelection` works correctly during the `onCreate` at first start of the activity, but not when I rotate the screen. I solved it by calling `setSelection` within the `onViewStateRestored` method of the fragment instead of calling it inside  the `onCreate` method. I'm not sure but I think that you can't use `setSelection` until the view is fully loaded, even if you can `findViewById` it.

Comment: This was the solution in my case. Basically, in `onCreate` that isn't the first one, the view state is then restored by the system. A `setSelection` in there will be reverted by the state restoration mechanism. The solution is to run `setSelection` after state restoration occurs

Comment: This looks promising but when I call `Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);` within the `onViewStateRestored()` method, it returns null (and it doesn't return null when I call it in `onCreate()`).

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
sp2.setAdapter(sp2.getAdapter());
sp2.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
sp2.setSelection(0, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked for me:

```
Spinner destSpinner = (Spinner)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit_event_destination);
destSpinner.setSelection(0);
String dest = events.get(pos).getDestination();
int routesPos = routes.indexOf(dest);
destSpinner.setAdapter(aa);
Log.d(TAG, "Dest: " + dest + ", pos: " + routesPos);
destSpinner.setSelection(routesPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, we may not set listeners because the spinner may be set to a certain value, and disabled as per requirement.

This can lead to setSelection() not selecting a value, since it needs a listener.

Make sure that the Spinner's setOnItemSelectedListener() is set to a custom listener like below.

Even if the spinner is disabled, we must set a listener like below, so that the setSelection() method works.

```
spinnerListener.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerListener);
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener spinnerListener = new 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
      //Your code
    }
}
spinnerListener.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: i dont know why you got -1, but your solution works for me.