# Android Spinner.setSelection(int, false) creates messed up Spinners

Tags: android, view, refresh, spinner

after using setSelection(int, false) like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048106/android-spinner-setselection-dosnt-work) because [i had troubles using the default setSelection(int) for initial setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048106/android-spinner-setselection-dosnt-work) it turns out that using the two param version messes up the spinner layout till the first manual selection takes place, details see image below.
Is there a way to "update" the spinner layout?

[image: setSelection 2param messed up spinner layout]

Comment: Well - so it turn's out running `Spinner.requestLayout()` fixes the problem but only works after the layouting is finished. NOW: what event can i look after so i know the "initial" layout is rendered and i can call `Spinner.requestLayout()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got it. I extedned the Spinner Class, added a var for saveing that this is the "first" pass and have overrwitten the onDraw method. after super.OnDraw() is called i can be sure that the layout has been drawn the first time and all data is passed to the spinner so to following requestLayout() will fix any layout errors. so i just test if this is the first onDraw with my var, if so i call requestLayout() and set the var to false. it's not the best way and maybe there is another event i could use that is run bevore the draw happens, but it's good enough for my needs.