# Spinner setSelection() not work

Tags: java, android, spinner

In my code `spinnerObj.setSelection(count)` dont work. I search it in google and dont find answer for me.

```
    count = 0;
    repairDetailsAdapter = new RepairDetailsAdapter(this, R.layout.gas_station_spinner_item, details);
    detailsOptionSpinner.setAdapter(repairDetailsAdapter);
    for (RepairDetail detail : details) {
        if (detail.getId() == tempDetail.getId()) {
            detailsOptionSpinner.setSelection(count);
            detailsOptionSpinner.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
```

This lines (from stackOverFlow) dont work:

```
 final int finalCount = count;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        detailsOptionSpinner.setSelection(finalCount);
        detailsOptionSpinner.invalidate();
    }
}, 13);
```

Comment: what you want ?? add more details

Comment: Just Use `spinner.setSelection(position, true);`

Comment: @Shevchenko Artem r u solve your problem?

Comment: no( try search answer or variants for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to set the spinner by using two arguments, the second using a boolean:

```
detailsOptionSpinner.setSelection(finalCount, true);
```

From the [developers page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) it shows:

```
setSelection(int position, boolean animate)
//Jump directly to a specific item in the adapter data.
```

Comment: http://joxi.ru/brRDWNDukBM421 - dont work for me(((

Comment: check both answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048106/android-spinner-setselection-doesnt-work

Comment: then y did you accept the answer? It leads to confusion in users..