# First Visible Position in a ListView doesn´t work without scroll

Tags: android, listview

I want to set the first visible item in a listView in, for example, 15. I try this and it works perfectly:

```
adapter = new HistoricAdapter(activity, lista);
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(15);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

but this doesn´t work:

```
adapter = new HistoricAdapter(activity, lista);
getListView().setSelection(15);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

why? I want the second option but it doesn´t work :-(

Comment: This may help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484528/android-setselection-having-no-effect-on-spinner

Comment: I did "Try moving the call to setSelection() after the call to setAdapter()" and it works!!! Thank you very much

Comment: I guess it should be other way around, set List adapter first then .setSelection();