# android spinner setSelection not working even after call setAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have this strange behavior, I have class that extend Dialog, and in onCreate() Method I load data and set it to my spinner and then call spinner.setSelection , the spinner is always select the first item.

I have tried

```
spinner.setSelection(position);
spinner.setSelection(position, true);
spinner.setSelection(position, false);
spinner.post (Runnable)

new Handler().postDelay (Runnable)
```

so please can any one tell me what is the problem ??

**EDIT**

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        int layourResId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("dialog_layout_default", "layout", mContext.getPackageName());
        setContentView(layourResId);
        initializeUIComponent();
        initializeUIComponentData();
        initializeUIComponentAction();
    }

    private void initializeUIComponent () {

        mCountriesSpinner       = (Spinner) findViewById(countriesResId);
        mOperatorsSpinner       = (Spinner) findViewById(operatorsResId);
    }

    private void initializeUIComponentData () {

        mCountriesSpinner.setAdapter(getCountriesAdapter());
        mOperatorsSpinner.setAdapter(getOperatorsAdapter(getCountriesAdapter().getItem(mCurrentSelectedCountry)));

        mMCC = PhoneUtils.getDeviceMCC(mContext);
        mMNC = PhoneUtils.getDeviceMNC(mContext);

        if (mMCC != null && mMNC != null) {

            String plmn = mMCC + mMNC;
            plmn = "41503";
            getDefaultSelection(plmn);
        }
    }


    private ArrayList<String> getCountries() {

        // logic here
        return countriesArray;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getOperators(String countryName) {

        // logic here
        return operatorsArray;
    }

    private ArrayAdapter<String> getCountriesAdapter() {

        // logic here
        return countriesArrayAdapter;
    }

    private ArrayAdapter<String> getOperatorsAdapter(String countryName) {

        // logic here
        return operatorsArrayAdapter;
    }

    private void getDefaultSelection(String plmn) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

            if (array.get(i).getPLMN().equals(plmn)) {

                object defaultSelection = array.get(i);
                if (defaultSelection != null) {

                    mCountriesSpinner.setSelection(getCountriesAdapter().getPosition(defaultSelection.getCountryName()));
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = getOperatorsAdapter(defaultSelection.getCountryName());
                    mOperatorsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    int position = adapter.getPosition(defaultChannel.getOperatorName());
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "position to be selected in operator " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mOperatorsSpinner.setSelection(position, true);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/default_container_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/please_choose_country"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/countries_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/please_choose_operator"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/operators_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/payment_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/payment" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It will be better to see your code.

Comment: @Anatol please review the code, I have updated the post.

Comment: where you call `getDefaultSelection`?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan in initializeUIComponentData after I get the MCC , MNC of the device.

Comment: did your code goes there? did you debug your code?

Comment: Yes, and the Toast is shown the correct position value.

Comment: can you post `xml` layout?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan : I have updated the post with XML

Comment: All thing seems right, check your code again, maybe you do one mistake

Comment: What is the value of position and how many items in adapter?

Comment: position = 1  and number of items in the array adapter = 2

Comment: See if my answer here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31774927/1617737