# spinner set selection doesn't working

Tags: android, spinner

I just need to add `setselection` method to my spinner by using the position that get from database.

I already try both(**in** is the position of text)

```
spinner.setselection(in);

spinner.setselection(in,true);
```

but it always shows first object in the array that used by the spinner

thanks for help

Comment: post your full code. @Shellz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: setSelection having no effect on Spinner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484528/android-setselection-having-no-effect-on-spinner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `setSelection()` is called after you done with spinner's `setAdapter()`.

Answer (score 4):

try this it will work

```
  for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                if (postion == Integer.parseInt(array.get(i))) {
                    spinner.setSelection(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the name of the item to get the position?

```
spinner.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter)spinner.getAdapter()).getPosition("Item Name​"));
```

Comment: I fetch the item from database

Comment: mcursor = sq.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                       + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " where "+ DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME + " =?",new String[]{grp});
               if (mcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                   do {

                       in=(mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_ID)));




                   } while (mcursor.moveToNext());